# Angular2 and array filter / find

Tags: angular, typescript

I have onInit processing where some DB data are being called and then combined together. I can't paste my whole method here as it is not formatted properly.

```
u.skills.forEach(s => {
    let skillEntry: SkillEntry = new SkillEntry();
    skillEntry.skill = s;

    let sbs: SkillBase[] = this.cachedSkillBases.filter(sb => sb.id == s.skillBaseId);
    if (sbs.length>0) {
      skillEntry.skillBase = sbs[0];
    } else {
      console.log('not found');
      this._userService.getSkillBase(s.skillBaseId).toPromise()
        .then(res => {
          skillEntry.skillBase = res;
          this.cachedSkillBases.push(res);
        });
    }
});
```

I have temp cache implemented here to make things faster but searching it doesn't work. Specifically I don't know why this filtering doesn't work if variable 's' exist and always has proper id

```
let sbs: SkillBase[] = this.cachedSkillBases.filter(sb => sb.id == s.skillBaseId);
```

Is it anything I  am missing here?

Comment: skillBaseId is set automatically on new()?

Comment: Just a guess, change your `==` to `===`. Make a difference?

Comment: skillBaseId comes from database fetched earlier. It always exist and is definitely not an issue here otherwise service call, which happens next, would also fail.
Making === doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Your cache implementation is async, it means that during loop you will get 100% cache miss and multiple duplicated requests. Promise `then` is executed async or some time *later*.

Comment: I have no promise and then calls over my cache. It is initialised together with the component and never cleared. It is accessed only by the marked line, it shouldn't be async then. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: You are calling http in else case, all this calls will be completed after forEach loop. Just add console.log to relevant places and you will see how it works.

Comment: that's fine but why entries cannot be found in the second run? After first call my cache should be fully populated and page refresh should cause no http calls but it does. Console also shows all entries to be in the cache before the loop.

Comment: Your code does not provide enough information to tell where is a bug. You have to use debugger/console.log to verify that your cache is populated and values have proper ids.

Answer (score 0):

All right, here is my full method then. I understand that the data are not available for the very first run but why my local cache doesn't work thereafter, it looks like to be ever empty or so? 
Unfortunately I can't paste whole method at once because it is rejected by this page (not properly formatted). Above this pasted here I have only method declaration, while cache arrays are declared at the component level.

** private getUsers() { ***

```
let fetchedUsers: User[]; 
let userEntries: UserEntry[] = [];
let skillEntries: SkillEntry[];

this._userService.getAllUsers(this.searchForm.userName, this.searchForm.skillName, this.searchForm.groupName) 
  .toPromise() 
  .then(result => {
    fetchedUsers = result;
    fetchedUsers.forEach(u => {
      let userEntry: UserEntry = new UserEntry();
      userEntry.detail = u;

      skillEntries = [];
      u.skills.forEach(s => {
        let skillEntry: SkillEntry = new SkillEntry();
        skillEntry.skill = s;

        let sbs: SkillBase;
        Promise.all(this.cachedSkillBases).then(res => {
          sbs = res.find(sb => sb.id == s.skillBaseId);
        });

        if (sbs) {
          skillEntry.skillBase = sbs;
        } else {
          this._userService.getSkillBase(s.skillBaseId).toPromise()
            .then(res => {
              console.log('got skills');
              skillEntry.skillBase = res;
              this.cachedSkillBases.push(res);
            });
        }

        if (s.skillDetailId) {
          let sds: SkillDetail;
          Promise.all(this.cachedSkillProficiencies).then(res => {
            sds = res.find(sd => sd.id == s.skillDetailId);
          });
          if (sds) {
            skillEntry.skillProficiency = sds;
          } else {
            this._userService.getSkillProficiency(s.skillDetailId).toPromise()
              .then(res => {
                console.log('got proficiencies');
                skillEntry.skillProficiency = res;
                this.cachedSkillProficiencies.push(res);
              });
          }
        }
        skillEntries.push(skillEntry);
      });
      console.log('setting users');
      userEntry.skills = skillEntries;
      userEntries.push(userEntry);
    })
  })
  .then(res => this.users = userEntries);
```

Comment: another acceptable solution would be making this code to return users at the end when everything else is completed, so the console.log('setting users') message would show up as the last one, not the first in the console as it is now. This way I can get rid of my not-working caches.